# How to use the offline version of NU Validator to check HTML 4.0.1 Strict files

Tags: java, html, validation, xhtml

This online version of [**NU Validator**](https://validator.nu/) allows users to specify different presets, e.g. HTML 4.0.1 Strict or XHTML. However, the [offline version](https://github.com/validator/validator) doesn't seem to allow users to specify presets.

1. Where can I find an offline version of the **Nu Validator** (or another tool) that allows me select presets other than XHTML and HTML5?
2. Are there undocumented Nu Validator command line parameters that allow users to specify different presets?